# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'colorpicker'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Yesterday I was using the bootstrap color picker: http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-colorpicker/

The simple HTML code is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/colorpicker/css/colorpicker.css">

    <div class="colorpicker" id="yellow">
        <a href=""></a>
    </div>

<script src="vendor/colorpicker/js/colorpicker.js"></script>
```

The js is:

```
$ ('. colorpicker'). colorpicker ()
```

Unfortunately I do not have any effect because the console in google chrome gives me this error:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'colorpicker'
```

I do not understand what is causing this error.

Comment: Spaces have meaning...

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you are having this code in `$(document).ready(function() {`

```
$ ('. colorpicker'). colorpicker ()
```

should be

```
$('.colorpicker').colorpicker()
```

Or the full code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.colorpicker').colorpicker();
} );
```

**Edit:** This is the page i tested and it is working.

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-colorpicker/css/colorpicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-colorpicker/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">  </script> 
<script src="http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-colorpicker/js/bootstrap-colorpicker.js">  </script> 

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.colorpicker').colorpicker();
});
</script> 

</head>
<body>
    <input class="colorpicker" id="yellow" />

</body>
</html>
```

*Note: basic `colorpicker` needs the element to be type input.*

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried with your code but the problem persists.

Is there any other possibilities?

Comment: @Marco Yes: that you have invalid code you didn't include in your question causing the problem, or you're not including the necessary libraries (e.g. the bootstrap colorpicker library). Have you checked to see where the exception actually occurs?

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this and wanted to contribute my 'fix':

**jquery was included twice**